# How to self-reference the variable to the left in an asignment in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave, self-reference

Say you need to store the name of all local variables in a script: `local = union(who,"local")`. Is there a function to replace the name ("local") with a reference to the variable which is to the left of the expression?

Update: For the sake of clarity, the sentence will be rewritten like `local = union(who, leftside())`, where the `leftside` function returns `local`.

Is there a sort of `leftside()` function with this behavior?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply use the code you have in your question?

Comment: There's no specific reason to use it, but it creates a dependency that I would like to get ride of. Also because I love this kind of metainstructions that Octave is equipped with.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such leftside() function. The documentation on the assignment operator (=) doesn't offer any insight either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
>> a = "test"
a = test
>> b = "rest "
b = rest
>> a = union(b,  a)
a =  erst
>> help union
'union' is a function from the file C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\share\octave\4.0
.3\m\set\union.m

 -- Function File: C = union (A, B)
 -- Function File: C = union (A, B, "rows")
 -- Function File: [C, IA, IB] = union (...)

 Return the unique elements that are in either A or B sorted in
 ascending order.
```

Update:

I'm not aware of such function. There are bunch of built in functions for internal use, that have the names like `__func_name__` and you may get a list of them if you type __ in the Octave's command window and press tab twice. At a glance I don't think there is a function, like the one you need, but take a more detailed look if you like.

Can you describe why do you need such behavior, maybe there is a different approach that can suit your needs i.e there are functions for programmatic creation of variables - `genvarname`.

Comment: Clearly I was not specific enough. Question updated with an example.